# Combine Proportional - Count data for feature selection & fitting methods

Tags: feature-selection, model, proportion, count-data, ratio

First of all, I would like to thank all of you who contribute in CV. I found it really helpful as a beginner in statistical learning.

Now regarding my question, as you have probably seen, I would like to combine proportional-count data for the classic feature selection methods (From the book "Introduction to Statistical Learning") and then use the appropriate fitting methods for interpretation & prediction as well.

---

**The variables**

To be more specific, I will give you an example:

I have the following variables and each observation represents a specific territory:

Proportional

P1. "Ratio of higher educated" - the number of high educated people divided by the total number **of all the population**

P2. "Ratio of smoking students" the number of students smoking divided by the total number **of all students**

P3. "Ratio of female teachers" the number of female teachers divided by the total number **of all teachers**

Count

C1. "Mean of wage" - the mean wage for a district **for all of the population**

C2. "Number of schools" - the total number of schools for an area

C3. "Total expentidure on education" - the expenditure in euro for education

---

**The scenarios**

1. C3 as response and only the proportional variables **(with different denominators as you can see)** as features i.e.

   C3=P1+P2+P3
2. C3 as response and **all** the other variables as features i.e.

   C3=P1+P2+P3+C1+C2
3. P1 as response and **all** the other variables as features i.e.

   P1=P2+C1+C2+C3

---

**Questions**

The main concern is, if in general we can combine proportional with mean/count data and **under which restrictions.**

I am worried that combining proportional features with different population (different underlying denominator) might not lead to accurate analysis and findings.

In addition the combination with mean/count data might makes the thing worse.

Finally which other things might need to consider? And which fitting methods can be used with safe for such type of variables?

For feature selection method, I am really keen to the Lasso (as probably I will add much more variables)

---

**Closing**

In case my topic is really broad I could specify it further.

All suggestions are welcome as well as reference for further study [the truth is that I couldn't find material explaining such attempt].

My main scenario is the first (1)